# How to use a static attribute with generics type and make sense?

Tags: angular, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, typescript-generics

I have a constructor and call static method to set a static variable.

```
export abstract class AbstractRepository<T extends Typegoose> {
  private static conn: SessionDb<T>; // <-- Compile error here!
  protected model: Model<InstanceType<T>, {}>;

  constructor(entity: T, collectionName: string){
    if(AbstractRepository.conn == null) AbstractRepository.conn = SessionDb.connect(entity);
    this.model = AbstractRepository.conn.getModel(collectionName);
  }  
}
```

How to type the `conn: SessionDb <T>` attribute?

This variable is a mongoose connection.

Does it make sense to save a singleton variable for future accesses?

Comment: Could you try to make this a [mcve] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)?  Or maybe provide a link to a project in a web IDE that shows what you're doing?  There's only one `AbstractRepository` at runtime and no `T`, so your singleton would get set exactly once and then never again.  If you want it set "once per XXX" you need to decide what XXX is and make code that actually has has a scope that supports it.  Maybe you want a factory function that produces classes?  Really not sure without a [mcve].

Comment: I can't really help without more information (particularly the definition of `SessionDb`), but as @jcalz said, there will be only one `static conn` variable which applies to all types `T`, so it seems wrong to have the type of that variable be dependent on `T`.  Since this is an abstract class, you might want to make `conn` an abstract variable and force your concretions to implement it.  But since you asked "Does it make sense to save a singleton variable for future accesses?" the answer is if `conn` is dependent on `T` then it doesn't.  Just make it an instance variable.

Comment: Excellent answers! I agree that I could have more information (including using an IDE), but the idea was to discuss how and if it makes sense to maintain a "typed" static variable and if so, how to type it.
I believe that the best implementation would be an singleton instance variable, as suggested by @linda-paiste.
Could you formulate an answer following this idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

When you have a generic class, the generic parameter `T` applies to **each instance** of the the class. When you create an instance of a generic class you can specify the type `T` like so `const myObj = new GenericClass<MyType>(args);` but usually you do not need to because your constructor signature tells typescript how the arguments used to create the instance relate to the generic `T`.

Through your constructor `constructor(entity: T, collectionName: string)` you have told typescript "take the type of the variable `entity` and use it as the generic `T` for this instance". So when you create a new instance by calling `const myObj = new ConcreteRepository(myEntity, myCollectionName);`, typescript will determine the type of `myObj` to be `ConcreteRepository<typeof myEntity>`. (I'm using the name `ConcreteRepository` to describe a class extending `AbstractRepository` since abstract classes can't be instantiated).

Meanwhile a `static` property applies to the class itself and therefore to **every instance**.

You can have many instances of `AbstractRepository` which can have many different values for `T` but they will all share the same value of `private static conn`.  This variable will have the type `T` of whichever specific instance was constructed first (since it's only set once), **not** the type `T` of the current instance.

**It simply does not make sense to have a static variable which is dependent on the generic `T`.**

### Solution 1

In order to ensure that each instance has a `SessionDb` which corresponds to its entity type, we make `conn` into an instance variable rather than a static variable.  Each instance sets its on `this.conn` in the constructor.

```
export abstract class AbstractRepository<T extends Typegoose> {
  protected conn: SessionDb<T>;
  protected model: Model<InstanceType<T>, {}>;

  constructor(entity: T, collectionName: string){
    this.conn = SessionDb.connect(entity);
    this.model = this.conn.getModel(collectionName);
  }
}
```

With this setup, the base class can be implemented by classes which are themselves generic:

```
export class ConcreteRepository<T extends Typegoose> extends AbstractRepository<T> {
}
```

Or by classes which are bound to a specific value of `T`:

```
export class SpecificRepository extends AbstractRepository<SpecificType> {
}
```

### Solution 2

`AbstractRepository` is an `abstract` class, meaning that it cannot be instantiated directly and can only be created by instantiated by classes that extend it.  If these extending classes each only apply to a specific type of entity, like the `SpecificRepository` example above, then you can have a separate `static conn` variable for each specific extending class.

It would look something vaguely like this (I don't know the details of some of these types):

```
export abstract class AbstractRepository<T extends Typegoose> {
  protected model: Model<InstanceType<T>, {}>;

  constructor(entity: T, collectionName: string){
    this.model = this.getConnection().getModel(collectionName);
  }

  abstract getConnection(): SessionDb<T>;
}

export class SpecificRepository extends AbstractRepository<SpecificType> {
    private static conn: SessionDb<SpecificType>;

    getConnection(): SessionDb<SpecificType> {
        if( SpecificRepository.conn === undefined) {
            // would need to know about enity somehow, either by storing this.entity 
            // or by having a static entity property on the class
            SpecificRepository.conn = SessionDb.connect(entity);
        }
        return SpecificRepository.conn;
    }
}
```

Here, the base class declares that each concretion must have a method `getConnection` which returns a `SessionDb` of the right type `T`.  We have left that implementation up to the child classes to figure out.  But since we know that this method must exist, it is safe for the base class to call it when doing `this.model = this.getConnection().getModel(collectionName);`

Comment: Solution 1 is closer to my problem! Thank you! :)